# Is speechsynthesis API officially provided by HTML5?

Tags: html, text-to-speech, mozilla, w3c, speech-synthesis

I understand speechsynthesis is used to convert the text-to-speech. But is it officially provided by HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [SpeechSynthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) is an interface for the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) and has very good browser support. HOWEVER, SpeechSynthesis is currently [EXPERIMENTAL](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/#tts-section) and it may change in ways that break current code. It is NOT recommended to be used in production as of writing this post.

[image: Browser compatibility screenshot]